# PYTHONSTARTUP variable doesn't get set in time to be picked up by python in Powershell script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, windows-7, environment-variables

```
$env:PYTHONSTARTUP = "E:\ftlcheckout\ps1XstoreCmds\WindowsPowerShell\oneCallMultipleTickets.py"

$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "One Call Multiple Tickets"

Write-Host "example: oneCallMultipleTickets(['123', '456', '789'])"

python
```

But when python runs it's like the `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable was never set, I can't run the `oneCallMultipleTickets` function.

However; if I exit python, and then run it again it works...

So is the `%PYTHONSTARTUP%` variable getting set, just too late?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. I've got a file that prints output so I can see when I load `python` from powershell that it's running. If you run `print(os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP'])` do you see the expected value? Is it possible something is causing python to be unable to read that file on the first run?

Comment: @MikeFrank Actually when I try what you suggested, I get no output, none, none at all, no matter what I type and when I press enter.  If I start python from the shell (as opposed to PowerShell doing it) I'm then able to print.